# Обновление UI во время выполнения метода

Tags: java, android

Привет всем. Пишу небольшой интерпретатор, в котором есть несколько функций, в том числе функция sleep(), а так же TextView,который служит роль лога.
К примеру есть код для интерпретатора:

```
printline("test") // пишет в лог текст
sleep(1000) // "спит" секунду
```

Выполнение выглядит следующим образом:
Запускается метод lineWorker, который в свою очередь крутит код. Проблема в том, что EditText обновится лишь тогда, когда программа закончится и метод lineWorker остановится (в данном случае слово test отобразится лишь через секунду). Но нужно, что бы при каждой отработанной функции в строках кода интерфейс обновлялся. Как выйти из этой ситуации?

Comment: Кажется я понял в чем проблема, но не уверен..У вас как происходит процесса сна? `Thread.sleep(long millis)`?

Comment: Именно...тут суть в другом, любая емкая задача заставит ждать весь поток. Здесь не это является злом, а тот факт, что весь код интепретатора выполняется в одном методе. Мне нужно создать второй поток, который этим займется. Что я и пробую

Comment: Пробовали связку `Thread/Handler`?

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно создать новый поток и после паузы выводить данные через метод `post`. Самый примитивный пример будет выглядеть вот так:

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
     public void run() {
         for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
            doWork();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            textView.post(new Runnable(){
                public void run() {
                    printline("test");
                }
            });
         }     
     }
});
```

И еще я не совсем понимаю зачем вы для лога используете `EditText` а не `TextView`.